# How do I add to string, neatly, based on 2 fields if null

Tags: c#, string, coding-style, refactoring, conditional-statements

I have some code which works totally fine but it looks a little bit messy/smelly.

Is there a way I can do this in a much cleaner way?

```
ViewBag.PageName = "Search Results for ";

if (searchViewModel.Code != null)  --checking Code value
     ViewBag.PageName += $"Product {searchViewModel.Code}";

if (searchViewModel.Region != null)
{
      if (searchViewModel.Code != null) --checking Code value Again!
           ViewBag.PageName += " and ";

      ViewBag.PageName += $"Region {searchViewModel.Region}";
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`. Anyway, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Don't think too much about it being clunky.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado, thank you I didn't know about isnullorwhitespace

Comment: Your code is fine. Although I like to use braces for any if statement (just my preference :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code. The only thing I might suggest is to consider using the [?: operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).  This is an "if/else" shortcut which evaluates an expression and returns a value based on whether the evaluation returns true or false. Combine with String.Concat, and it is clear what conditions drive each part of the PageName:

```
ViewBag.PageName = String.Concat("Search Results for ",
    (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchViewModel.Code)) ? $"Product {searchViewModel.Code}" : "",
    (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchViewModel.Code) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchViewModel.Region)) ? " and " : "",
    (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchViewModel.Region)) ? $"Region {searchViewModel.Region}" : ""
)
```

(and +1 to @John for suggesting IsNullOrWhiteSpace()).

Comment: Thank you, I think that looks a lot neater